# Error with firebase and unity in android devices

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I have been fighting for several days with the same error without any result.

When I import the `unitypackage` from Firebase database to a new drive project prepared to run on Android devices, the following error occurs:

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TREI5.png)

The project shown in the image is that of Google [mechahamster](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)

On the other hand, if you run it on PC devices, it does not sell the error, and everything works correctly. I suspect that it may have some flaw with the Android SDK.

Any ideas?

Comment: im no unity developer, BUT, its an error that is similar to a NPE. basically the object has no reference. please read the error and understand the error and go from there. add breakpoints in your code. more than likely you aren't referring to the object in your code but you are looking to use it.

Comment: tooooons of stuff to read up on... which im sure you did. https://www.google.com/search?q=object+reference+not+set+to+an+instance+of+an+object+unity&rlz=1C5CHFA_enUS784US784&oq=object+reference+not+&aqs=chrome.2.0j69i57j0l4.6509j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Thanks for answering DroiDev. the problem is that the error has nothing else to import the package of firebase, therefore there is no code of mine, I have searched in many places the same error without any result.

Comment: i dont think it has anything to do with firebase. maybe go on the unity forums rather than stackoverflow.